# Reading RSysLog tcp messages

Tags: c++, linux, tcp, rsyslog

I am attempting to read RSysLog log from a machine running debian linux.  I have setup a server on another linux machine and can read the log messages.  I want to be able to read them on a windows machine from c++.  I have setup the remote machine to distribute the logs to the windows machine. I have an application running on the machine that writes log messages at intervals.  The setup to distribute the logs is of the form local1.* @@192.168.1.8 which is the ip address of the windows machine.

I know I am not thinking about this correctly, the remote machine does not attempt a connection to the windows machine and the program hangs on the accept call.

Edit:
After some further testing I figured out that the connect occurs when the syslog daemon is started.  To use tcp the server has to be alive when the daemon is started.  This is not what I want so I will work more with the UDP implementation.

Here is the code I am using, I have tried to make it as simple as possible.

```
WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult;

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

SOCKET h;

h = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (h == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    std::cout << "Socket Failure: " << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
std::cout << "Socket Success: " << std::endl;

// The server 
sockaddr_in server;
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.8");
server.sin_port = htons(514);

iResult = bind(h, (SOCKADDR *)&server, sizeof(server));
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    std::cout << "Bind Failure: " << std::endl;
    closesocket(h);
    return 1;
}
std::cout << "Bind Success: " << std::endl;

if (listen(h, SOMAXCONN))
{
    std::cout << "Listen Failure: " << std::endl;
    errcode = WSAGetLastError();
    closesocket(h);
    return 1;
}
std::cout << "Listen Success: " << std::endl;

struct sockaddr_in dest;
int addrlen = sizeof(dest);
SOCKET s = accept(h, (sockaddr *)&dest, &addrlen);
if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    std::cout << "Accept Failure: " << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Accept Success: " << std::endl;
}
WSACleanup();

return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `SOCK_DGRAM` instead of `SOCK_STREAM`.

Syslog on [port 514](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) seems to send UDP packets, not TCP.

You could also try to connect to the server with a browser to check if all the rest is ok (seems ok though) - 192.168.1.8:514 (while still in TCP mode).

Comment: syslog can send either UDP packets or TCP packets.  I was going to work on a UDP implementation until I can figure this out.  On the remote machine using local1.* @@192.168.1.8  the @@ tells the forwarder to send tcp and if I uses local1.* @192.168.1.8 it would send UDP. I will look into SOCK_DGRAM.  Thank you.

Comment: @Sting - The server seems ok - when testing from a browser on port 1024 all is well. So it must be TCP vs UDP, or the configuration of syslog (nothing coming in), or a port being blocked on the network maybe.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I implemented a quick and dirty udp listener and it blocks on recvfrom.  I looked at the windows firewall and it llows any think for this application.  I will look at the firewall on the remote machine.  I suspect this is good also as another linux machine can read the forwarded messages using the stock rsyslog mechanism.

Comment: @Sting - It might be interesting to take a look at the traffic with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Danny:  Thanks for your help, I was starting to use the ncat tool and for no reason I can think of the udp implementation started to work.  I did some experimentation and think the TCP will only work if the server is alive when the syslog daemon is started on the remote machine and I really only want to ake periodic checks so I think I will go with the udp.  Thanks again.